Mouse position not working with following cinemachine camera, solved
I have a top-down game, similar to vampire survivors, and I just implemented a bow weapon. The camera is set to follow the player in cinemachine virtual camera. The shooting works good, but only on 0,0,0 or in very near radius around it. The problem is that when you go in any direction, the arrow will start going in that direction only.
The code that gets the direction of the arrow(in Update):
Ray ray = mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit raycastHit))
    {
         shootDirection = raycastHit.point;
         shootDirection.y = 0f;
         arrowClass.SetUpArrowDirection(shootDirection);
    }

I tried searching online, and changing a code a little bit, but nothing worked.

normally a "point" is not a direction, as if you have a point 1,1 and you are 0,0, sure it is 1,1 away, but if you are at 4,2, then its -3,-1 away.....  second, if you're using cinemachine, its been a while does the current camera claim to be mainCamera?

@BugFinder Turns out that cinemachine is not responsible for the bug, since it also happens without it.

OK, but my point about the direction still remains

@Bugfinder After more testing, i relized that the direction is right if the player is not moving. So the point is fine, but the starting position is the problem

And only in the direction that the player is facing. I think that increasing the speed of arrows will solve it

It works, funnily enough it didnt work becouse i redoused the speed when testing
